# Detect USB device using native library on Android

Tags: android, c++, c, usb, udev

I would like to know how to detect a USB device which is connected to an Android device (as a host). In normal Linux I just use libudev to do that. What's the equivalent in Android?

Any documentation about it?

Thank you

Comment: Android does not use `udev`. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Android devices which officially support USB host mode do so with Java-level APIs, so that is what you should use, from the dvm already in the process hosting your native library.

Comment: I'm trying to use the hot plug HAL of android to recognize when a specific usb device was connected to the host. My point was that in Linux we can use udev to do so. So my question was if there was any other alternative on Android to udev.

Comment: Well, you could figure out how the Android APIs are detecting it, but on a secured device you may not be able to directly use that mechanism yourself.

Comment: Refer to Android USB Host. You should use intent filters to detect devices that are plugged in. In order to enumerate devices that are plugged in, refer to the USB Manager class. There is an example to list devices and get their VID,PID and the device name

Answer (score 0):

It was past long time but I would like to add some finding with the hope to help others.

There is an Android native solution using Android's libusbhost library to access a USB device from native C++ (by @sonicdebris from github.com). Here is the [link](https://github.com/sonicdebris/android-native-usb-test). It is a PoC and not complete but it will give some idea about the problem.

There is also a recipe about the question in the official Android documentation but it is Java. Here is the [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host#discovering-d).